# Docker compose error loading conf/server.xml file for Tomcat cluster

Tags: tomcat, nginx, docker-compose

I get this error when I run the docker-compose file.

```
WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Catalina.start 
using conf/server.xml: Error at (134, 114) : 
org.apache.catalina.tribes.group
  .interceptors.MessageDispatch15Interceptor

SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Cannot start server. 
Server instance is not configured.
```

Tomcat conf/server.xml :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <Service name="Catalina">

    <Connector port="10080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="10443" />

    <Connector port="10009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="10443" />

    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"
                 channelSendOptions="8">

          <Manager className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager"
                   expireSessionsOnShutdown="false"
                   notifyListenersOnReplication="true"/>

          <Channel className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.GroupChannel">
            <Membership className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastService"
                        address="228.0.0.4"
                        port="45564"
                        frequency="500"
                        dropTime="3000"/>
            <Receiver className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.NioReceiver"
                      address="auto"
                      port="4000"
                      autoBind="100"
                      selectorTimeout="5000"
                      maxThreads="6"/>

            <Sender className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.ReplicationTransmitter">
              <Transport className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.PooledParallelSender"/>
            </Sender>
            <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.TcpFailureDetector"/>
            <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.MessageDispatch15Interceptor"/>
          </Channel>

          <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve"
                 filter=""/>
          <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteBinderValve"/>


          <ClusterListener className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.ClusterSessionListener"/>
        </Cluster>

      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI: I was able to get it working by downgrading to Tomcat7  and not using the MessageDispatch15Interceptor :  https://github.com/djangofan/docker-tomcat7-cluster